# How to configure package configuration files for Sublime Text 3 on a mac?

Tags: sublimetext

I'm having trouble setting the Pig config for sublime text 3.  I tried to set the package configuration through preferences but it opens up a readonly version of configuration file that I cannot save.  When I try to look for the actual file in the file system it doesn't exist.

Specifically I'm looking for

Pig.sublime-settings

when I mouse over the configuration file that the preferences opens up it points to

~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Apache Pig/Pig.sublime-settings

but when I look for that folder Apache Pig doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you go to `Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Package Settings -> Pig` there should be two options - `Settings - Default` and `Settings - User`. Open the `Default` file, and it should contain all the settings options (you've done this already). Next, open the `User` file, which will be empty. Copy the entire contents of `Default` to `User`, and close `Default`. You can now make any changes you want to `User`, and it will be saved as `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Pig.sublime-settings`.

This is the template for all package settings in ST3 - the default settings are intentionally set to be read-only, so you can't accidentally mess something up beyond repair. You make your desired changes in the User settings file, and if anything goes wrong you can always delete the file and start over, or just re-copy the default settings.